How skip downloading 'robot.txt.tmp' files?
I sometimes want to only download media files from a single web page, such as gif files, which I figured out with:
wget -P c:\temp -A .gif -r -l 1 -H -nd 'https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=saviof.mayacode'

but this also downloads a bunch of robot.text.temp files:
F:\temp\robots.txt.tmp
F:\temp\robots.txt.tmp.1
F:\temp\robots.txt.tmp.2
F:\temp\robots.txt.tmp.3
F:\temp\robots.txt.tmp.4
F:\temp\autocomplete.gif
F:\temp\send_to_maya.gif
F:\temp\syntax_highlight.gif
F:\temp\variables.gif

Is it possible to skip these files and only get the gif files?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

hello. What the option -e robots=off gives you ?
